# Trying to understand variance components methods in quantitative genetics

Tags: maximum-likelihood, covariance-matrix, genetics

As described [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3064490/#), the variance components approach to quantitative genetic analysis assumes a mixed linear model,
$$
\textbf{y}=\textbf{X}\beta{}+\textbf{g}+\textbf{e}\textrm{,}
$$where $\textbf{y}$ is the trait vector, $\textbf{X}$ is a matrix of nuisance covariates (age, sex, and so on), $\beta{}$ is a vector of covariate coefficients, $\textbf{g}$ is the random effect of genes, and $\textbf{e}$ is the random of effect of environment. The variance of $\textbf{y}$, also known as the phenotypic variance, has two components, genetic variance and environmental variance,
$$
\sigma^{2}_p=\sigma^{2}_g+\sigma^{2}_e\textrm{.}
$$
From this, the heritability of $\textbf{y}$ can be defined as
$$
h^2=\frac{\sigma^{2}_g}{\sigma^{2}_p}\textrm{.}
$$
To estimate $h^2$ from family data, one finds optimal values of $\sigma^{2}_g$ and $\sigma^{2}_e$ using the equation
$$
\Omega=2\Phi\sigma^{2}_g+\sigma^{2}_e.
$$
Here, $\Phi$ is a $n$-by-$n$ matrix where $n$ is the number of subjects and $\Phi{}_i{_j}$ describes the degree of genetic relatedness between the $i$th and $j$th subjects. $\textbf{I}$ is a $n$-by-$n$ identity matrix. In the linked article, the first matrix is described as follows:

> Here Ω is an N-by-N matrix, where N is the number of individuals in
>   the data set, whose elements are the observed covariances in phenotype
>   for each pair of individuals in the data set.

I don't understand how $\Omega$ is computed in practice, or consequently, how maximum-likelihood is used to obtain values for $\sigma^{2}_g$ and $\sigma^{2}_e$. A simple worked-out example would be illuminating, but I haven't seen anything like this in the literature.